# How come in IE 8, my images are 1px tall?

Tags: html, browser

```
<img src="blah.png" width="150" height="auto">
```

In Firefox/Chrome/Safari, this image will display correctly. But in IE, the picture is only 1 pixel tall (but the width is 150)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto` is not a valid value for the `height` attribute (which must specify a [*length*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-length) – which can be either absolute in pixels or a percentage). Just leave it out and it should work.

I guess the other browsers are just a bit more lenient with errors in that case, but those are issues you only run into when writing invalid markup.